# A formula for functions of diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In one journal article that I have read recently, they use the following formula for computing functions of diagonalizable matrices:
$$f(A)_{ij} = \sum_{\lambda \in \textrm{sp}A} \frac{x_i(\lambda) y_j(\lambda)}{\sum_{k=1}^n  x_k(\lambda)y_k(\lambda)} f(\lambda).$$
Here, $A$ is an $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrix, $f$ is a function such as $x^n$ or $e^x$, $f(A)_{ij}$ is the $(i,j)$-th element of the matrix $f(A)$, $\textrm{sp}A$ is the spectrum of $A$, $x(\lambda) = [x_i(\lambda)]^T$ is the right eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$ and $y(\lambda) = [y_j(\lambda)]$ is the left eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$.

The formula appears unreferenced in the article, and is supposed to hold for every diagonalizable matrix $A$ without any other assumptions.

However, I have a trouble to prove the formula for myself. I have only managed to prove it in the case when the eigenvectors form an orthogonal basis. So I would like to ask if somebody knows either the proof or the reference for this formula.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea: If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A = P D P^{-1}$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, and $P$ is the matrix of (right) eigenvectors. Then
$$f(A) = P\cdot f(D)\cdot P^{-1}.$$

[Outline of proof: $$A^2 = (PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1}) = P(D^2)P^{-1},$$
where $D^2$ turns out to be the matrix you get by squaring all the entries on the diagonal.

This continues for larger powers of $A$. Once you have that, you get all the analytic functions --- those whose power series converge for all reals --- so $e^A = P \cdot e^D \cdot P^{-1}$, where $e^D$ means take $e^\lambda$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ and make a diagonal matrix out of the answers.]

The article is explicitly multiplying $P \cdot f(D) \cdot P^{-1}$ "by hand"; the columns of $P$ are the transpose of the $x$'s, the rows of $P^{-1}$ are the transpose of the $y$'s, and the eigenvalues are the $\lambda$'s.

(Note that in the summation, if an eigenvalue is repeated, that term is added more than once.)